# SwiftUI: Issue with data binding for passing back the updated value to caller

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I have 2 views where the

- first view passes list of items and selected item in that to second view and
- second view returns the updated selected item if user changes.

I am getting error 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context' when i am sending the model property 'idx'.

```
//I cant make any changes to this model so cant confirm it with ObservableObject or put a bool property like 'isSelected'
class Model {
  var idx: String?
  ....
}

class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {

    var list: [Model]
    @Published var selectedModel: Model?

    func getSecondViewModel() -> SecondViewModel {
        let vm2 = SecondViewModel( //error >> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
           list: list,
           selected: selectedModel?.idx // >> issue might be here but showing at above line
        )
        return vm2
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservableObject firstViewModel: FirstViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        ..
        
        .sheet(isPresented: $showView2) {
            NavigationView {

                SecondView(viewModel: firstViewModel.getSecondViewModel())
            }
        }
        
        ..
    }
}


class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var list: [Model]
    @Published var selected: String?
    
    init(list: [Model], selected: Published<String?>) {
        self.list = list
        _selected = selected
    }
    
    func setSelected(idx: String) {
        self.selected = idx
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {
    
    @ObservableObject secondViewModel: SecondViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        ...
        
            .onTapGesture {
                secondViewModel.setSelected(idx: selectedIndex)
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        ...
        
    }
}
```

In case if I am sending 'Model' object directly to the SecondViewModel its working fine. I need to make changes the type and couple of other areas and instantiate the SecondViewModel as below

```
let vm2 = SecondViewModel(
    list: list,
    selected: _selectedModel
)
```

Since I need only idx I don't want to send entire model.

Also the reason for error might be but not sure the Model is @Published and the idx is not.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hmm, so you want the `selected` property in `SecondViewModel` to be linked to `FirstViewModel`?

Comment: Why don’t you want to send *the entire model*? If you want to segregate the interface, use a protocol instead of making a copy of the original model into a different type again and again! Then you can pass the original model without concerning about extra properties

Comment: @aheze Yes the selected items `idx` property of `SecondViewModel` to be linked to the `idx` property of the Model instance(selectedModel) present in `FirstViewModel`

Comment: @pradeep agree with Mojtaba — would probably be easier to just pass down `FirstViewModel` into `SecondView`. If you absolutely need the separate property you could try a `Binding`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Yes thats right. If there is no option I pass the entire model. Why I am asking is its unnecessary to send all the data to send VM. Also Its not possible for my case to use protocols as I can't modify the Model class due to some other reasons.

Comment: @aheze I dont think MojtabaHosseini is suggesting to pass the entire ViewModel to SecondView. He is asking why not to send the entire Model class just as I have done in the question. As I was looking to send only property

Comment: Some observations: your `func getSecondViewModel()` does not return anything.
 If you make it to return a `SecondViewModel`, it **must not be** a different one each time.
 In other words you need to create **ony one** `SecondViewModel` that you use.
 Re-structure your code so that you do not **nest** ObservableObject.
 Also in `SecondViewModel` use: `init(list: [Model], selected: String?) { self.list = list   self.selected = selected }`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine The 1st point is a miss, updated code to return the VM. For 2nd point selected should be of type Published, else it wont update the instance in the FirstViewModel.

Comment: As I said, if you make it to return a `SecondViewModel`, it **must not be** a different one each time. In other words you need to create **only one single source of truth**, `SecondViewModel`, that you use. 
 Note, from your comment: `...Why I am asking is its unnecessary to send all the data to send VM.`, 
the data is not sent anywhere, `FirstViewModel` is a class, only its reference is passed along, not the "data", it is 
extremely efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code, in keeping with your original code that allows you to
use the `secondViewModel` as a nested model.

It passes `firstViewModel` to the `SecondView`, because
`secondViewModel` is contained in the `firstViewModel`. It also uses
`firstViewModel.objectWillChange.send()` to tell the model to update.

My comment is still valid, you need to create **only one** `SecondViewModel` that you use. Currently, your `func getSecondViewModel()` returns a new `SecondViewModel` every time you use it.

Re-structure your code so that you do not need to have nested ObservableObjects.

```
struct Model {
    var idx = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var firstMdl = FirstViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 55){
            FirstView(firstViewModel: firstMdl)
            Text(firstMdl.secondViewModel.selected ?? "secondViewModel NO selected data")
        }
    }
 
}

class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var list: [Model]
    @Published var selectedModel: Model?
    
    let secondViewModel: SecondViewModel // <-- here only one source of truth
    
    // -- here
    init() {
        self.list = []
        self.selectedModel = nil
        self.secondViewModel = SecondViewModel(list: list, selected: nil)
    }
    
    // -- here
    func getSecondViewModel() -> SecondViewModel {
        secondViewModel.selected = selectedModel?.idx
        return secondViewModel
    }
}

class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var list: [Model]
    @Published var selected: String?
    
    init(list: [Model], selected: String?) {  // <-- here
        self.list = list
        self.selected = selected  // <-- here
    }
    
    func setSelected(idx: String) {
        selected = idx
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var firstViewModel: FirstViewModel  // <-- here
    @State var showView2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("click me", action: {showView2 = true}).padding(20).border(.green)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showView2) {
                SecondView(firstViewModel: firstViewModel)
            }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var firstViewModel: FirstViewModel  // <-- here
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var selectedIndex = "---> have some data now"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondView tap here to dismiss").padding(20).border(.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                firstViewModel.objectWillChange.send()  // <-- here
                firstViewModel.getSecondViewModel().setSelected(idx: selectedIndex)  // <-- here
                // alternatively
                // firstViewModel.secondViewModel.selected = selectedIndex
                dismiss()
            }
    }
}
```